# How do I make a global operator defined externally a friend

Tags: c++

In a class I can declare a operator as friend and define it at the same place, then not belonging to the namespace of the class but the outer namespace like this:

```
friend bool operator ==( typename ring_buffer<T>::const_iterator left, typename ring_buffer<T>::const_iterator right )
{
    return left.m_it == right.m_it;
}
```

How do I *declare* this operator as a friend when it is *defined* externally, i.e. outside the class ?

Comment: You might have issue as there is `template` involved especially with inner type which disallow deduction of parent.

Comment: Issue is that you have a non-template function (but which is a template entity). outside of the class, you cannot have equivalent.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this does not define a function template, but a single overload specific to the instantiation of the surrounding template.
A function template instantiation doesn't "count" as an overload.
(This is one of those cases where the differences between template function instantiations and overloads get annoying.)

If you want to move the definitions outside, you can't use a template but need to implement each overload explicitly, like this:

```
bool operator ==(ring_buffer<int>::const_iterator left, 
                 ring_buffer<int>::const_iterator right )
{
   return left.m_it == right.m_it;
}


bool operator ==(ring_buffer<float>::const_iterator left, 
                 ring_buffer<float>::const_iterator right )
{
   return left.m_it == right.m_it;
}

... and so on ...
```

This needs to be done manually and gets very tedious, so it is never done in practice.
(You can streamline the tedium with a macro, but in my opinion, it's not worth the trouble.)

Answer (score 0):

Put to the class declaration this `friend` declaration.

```cpp
friend bool operator ==( typename ring_buffer<T>::const_iterator left, typename ring_buffer<T>::const_iterator right );
```

From: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_friend_functions.htm

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the `public` section of the class.

Comment: This doesn't work, the compiler inside the ==-operator complains that I don't have access to the private fields of the iterator-class (Error C2248 'ring_buffer<int>::iterator::m_it': cannot access protected member declared in class 'ring_buffer<int>::iterator'). I think the problem here is that I've to explain the compiler that the operator belongs to the global namespace.

Comment: @BonitaMontero - Then your question should contain a [mre], and not a blurb.

Comment: @BonitaMontero: Issue is that you have a non-template function (but which is a template entity). outside of the class, you cannot have equivalent.

Comment: @BonitaMontero would an alternative member function form resolve your issue? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators